# Why does my NXT colour sensor not recognise colour on my iPhone?

Tags: nxt, ios

If I point the colour sensor to my iPhone it does not recognise it, but if I point it to a piece of paper, it does.

Does anyone know if there is a solution for this?
I found some documentation online, and saw [this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7pIS69teEvw) video, he's doing pretty much what I want.

Comment: if its the iPhone screen it probably has to do with the glare/glossiness of the screen

Comment: Yeah that's right

Answer (score 7):

The robot in the video has a custom light sensor, a more advanced [HiTechnic color sensor V2](http://www.hitechnic.com/cgi-bin/commerce.cgi?preadd=action&key=NCO1038) which can detect an extended range of 15 colours. The stand colour sensor can detect six (white, black, red, blue, green and yellow).

[image]

> The sensors are based on different principles. LEGO sensor uses a RGB
>   LED, and successively shines red, green and blue light on the object.
>   Reflected light is collected by a light sensor sensitive to all
>   wavelength. HiTechnic one has a white LED, and a specialized color
>   sensitive chip. This chip has three sensitive areas covered by red,
>   green and blue filters. **An added advantage of HiTechnic method is that
>   it can detect the color of light sent on it (in passive mode, with the
>   white LED shut off).**

[[Source]](http://www.philohome.com/colcomp/cc.htm)

A direct LED light against an iPhone's screen will reflect the light back into the sensor, making it difficult for the sensor to detect colour.